# NPE on safe called variable in kotlin. What is the reason behind it and How it can be solved?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have following piece of code.

```
    var date1: Date? = null

    try {
        date1 = df1.parse(startDate)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val cal1: Calendar? = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal1?.time = date1
```

And I have received NPE on last line. Here is the stacktrace. It's not very frequent but it is occurring sometimes.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
       at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1749)
       at ui.interviewslot.InterviewSlotActivity.getDates(InterviewSlotActivity.kt:443)
       at ui.interviewslot.InterviewSlotActivity.setUI(InterviewSlotActivity.kt:125)
       at ui.interviewslot.InterviewSlotActivity$onCreate$1.onChanged(InterviewSlotActivity.kt:78)
       at ui.interviewslot.InterviewSlotActivity$onCreate$1.onChanged(InterviewSlotActivity.kt:33)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:131)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:289)
       at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Device : HUAWEI P20 Lite
Android version : 8.0.0

Comment: What if date1 is null?

Comment: Please post the result of `println(date)`

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Sorry guys, I missed this part. I didn't checked what cal1?.time does. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `calendar.setTime` method calls `getTime` on it's argument. This will cause an NPE if the argument is `null`. My guess is that your `date1` variable is null because the parsing failed. You can fix it by doing this:

```
val date1: Date? = try {
    df1.parse(startDate)
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    null
}

if (date1 != null) {
    val cal1: Calendar? = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal1?.time = date1
}
```